# Image of the boundary is equal to the boundary of image.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

In my studies of continuum mechanics, I encountered a question which I shall pose. Suppose that $f:U \to V$ is some function with domain $U\subseteq M$ and codomain $V\subseteq N$. Assume $(M,d_M)$ and $(N,d_N)$ are some metric spaces.

1. Suppose that for all $A\subseteq U$ we have $ f (\partial_M A)=\partial_N f(A)$? Then what are the implications for $f$? Should it necessarily be a homeomorphism?
2. Conversely, if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then does is imply that for all $A\subseteq U$ we have $ f (\partial_M A)=\partial_N f(A)$?

Comment: Is $R=\mathbb R$ the real numbers? And what can $D$ be, a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $\mathbb R$, or any topological space?

Comment: I presume that $f$ is assumed to be continuous?

Comment: If $R$ is meant to be real numbers, $D$ a closed interval in $R$ (possibly whole $R$) and $f$ continuous then the answer is: $\partial B=f(\partial A)$ if and only if $f$ is a homeomorphism onto image. In more general case if $D$ is compact then $f$ being a homeomorphism onto image is always sufficient. But definitely there is no easy necessary condition.